# WAMP 404 VirtualHosts

Tags: wamp

I am a student doing an internship as part of my college course and I'm having alot of problems with using apache and virtual hosts. I have to use WAMP as my dev environment and when I made changes to the windows hosts file and httpd-vhosts.conf file it has borked my WAMP server making it unusable. I have uploaded the following files to pastebin

- Windows hosts file:      http://pastebin.com/X9XyJHEX
- httpd.conf file:     http://pastebin.com/DHULTyKChttp://pastebin.com/UvptYTsy
- httpd-vhosts.conf file:

Ok so here are the symptoms I can browse to localhost and 127.0.0.1 and I am presented with the WAMP Server welcome screen but the virtual hosts I have setup are not showing up under the virtual hosts directory. I cannot access PHPMyAdmin as when I browse to "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/" I get the following error:

> Not Found The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.

I have been googling this and trying all kinds of variations of how to get this virtual hosts setup but none of them work and all of them result in the same problem a crippled WAMP sever that is now unusable. Can anyone see why these files (which according to everything I can find on google whos text is correct and causing no issues) are not working. No one in the company seems to have any ideas (Ive copied their files/setups and it makes no difference), this has stopped me dead in my tracks for the past two days and I am at my wits end. This has taken up so much time that if I dont get it resolved in the next day I will have to either uninstall WAMP or do a fresh install of windows. Drastic I know but I do not have any more time to be pricking around with this and right now if I dont do something Im going to drop kick this PC out the door!

Can anyone point me to a very good, very detailed and n00b orientated tutorial on how to setup VirtualHosts and use them correctly. I will gladly update this with my findings as I go as no one should have to wade through this amount of bullshit and nonsense for no bloody good reason!!!!

Comment: This should probably go to http://serverfault.com/ but is definitely not the right question for stackoverflow, which is about programming questions.